# One-liner to find all mail servers in AD domain with Powershell

Tags: exchange, powershell, scripting

I would like to use powershell to find all available mail servers in a given network segment, or domain wide.  Is this possible and how could you do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

> Get-ExchangeServer -domain [DOMAIN NAME]

Answer (score 1):

`get-mailboxserver` from the Exchange powershell is supposed to be able to do this.

```
Name                      ManagedFolderAssi ClusteredStorageT MapiEncryptionReq
                          stantSchedule     ype               uired
----                      ----------------- ----------------- -----------------
EXCHMAILBOX3                                Disabled          False
EXCHMAILBOX4                                Disabled          False
EXCHMAILBOX1                                Disabled          False
EXCHMAILBOX2                                Disabled          False
```

Is there some part of your environment that makes this not work for you?

Comment: I'd do Get-Exchangeserver - that should do all roles, not just mailbox servers.

Answer (score 0):

If they're exchange, you can probably use Powershell to query AD for that, sure. If they're not exchange, it depends on how you define "mailserver", and regardless, that will be much more difficult.

- Good answer below for Exchange, exactly what I figured there would be.